# From CSV to tContextLoad

Tags: talend

I have a CSV parameter file :

[image]

And a job talend where I’m supposed to get this data back for loading into contexts :

[image]

But I get => tContextLoad_3 set key "First;Last" with value "Olivia;Anderson".

I would like to get something like => tContextLoad_3 set key "First" with value "Olivia;Amelia;Ava;Isabella" or "Olivia,Amelia,Ava,Isabella"...

I specify, I cannot change the format of my csv configuration file.

I tried to change the tfileinputdelimited several times but I can’t, Do you have any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tDenormalize, which is to denormalize one column in a delimited file.

[image]

Comment: On tSplitRow you put well =>
key : "start_date", "end_date" / value : row7.start_date, row7.end_date ?